# IS the run time library just some dynamicly linked library files?

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll, runtime

The C standard library for example has some standard functions like `printf`,.

What exactly the relation between the standard library and the run time library ?

Is the run time library just the dll's (under windows) part of the standard library? so when I call the `printf` in my program , the compiler links my program "dynamically" to the dll file(MSVCR100D.dll) that exports the `printf` so both my program and that dll are loaded in memory at loading time ?

**is that dll (MSVCR100D.dll) that has the exported `printf` is exactly the C run time library or the run time library is something else???**

Comment: What does this have to do with C++ ?

Comment: @PaulR isn't the C++ has a run time library ?

Comment: Yes, but you seem to be asking about the C runtime library in the question ?

Comment: @PaulR I'm asking about **the run time libraries** , I want to understand what they are! and c/c++ use run time library, I guess the question is related to c++ even more than the windows, the C run time was merely an example to what I mean.

Comment: The runtime includes, but is not limited to, the standard library.  (For example, it also includes code that may be called from the prolog and epilog code that the compiler inserts into every function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of MSVC, the runtime library MSVCRxxx.DLL contains all of the code for the C/C++ standard library.

Comment: thank you very much, so the "run time" library is the dynamically linked libraries (dll files) of the standard library?, in this case is the MSVCRxxx.DLL ?

Comment: Correct. Happy to help.